# Negative bar chart of highcharts in chartjs

Tags: highcharts, chart.js

I been playing with Chartjs to generate something like [highcharts](https://www.highcharts.com/demo/bar-negative-stack) but couldn't bring it close. The application is finished and it seems a waste to buy highcharts, migrate from chartjs for this single chart.

Is there a way Chartjs can output something like that? I did try creating two horizontal bar charts side-by-side in separate canvas; while i saw the output; the behavior is not what I want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a horizontal [stacked](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/bar.html#stacked-bar-chart) barchart with two datasets. Add negative values to the dataset on the left (male) but display the absolute value in the callbacks of the xAxis and the tooltip.

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
var data = {
  labels: ["20-30", "10-20", "0-10"],
  datasets: [{
      label: "Male",
      backgroundColor: "rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)",
      borderColor: "rgb(54, 162, 235)",
      borderWidth: 2,
      data: [-65, -59, -20],
    }, {
      label: "Female",
      backgroundColor: "rgba(255,99,132,0.2)",
      borderColor: "rgba(255,99,132,1)",
      borderWidth: 2,
      data: [72, 45, 18],
    },

  ]
};

var myBarChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'horizontalBar',
  data: data,
  options: {
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        stacked: true
      }],
      xAxes: [{
       ticks: {
          callback: function(value, index, values) {
           return Math.abs(value);
          }
        }
      }]
    },
    tooltips: {
      callbacks: {
        label: function(tooltipItems, data) {
         return data.datasets[tooltipItems.datasetIndex].label  + ": " +  Math.abs(tooltipItems.xLabel);
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.1/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
```